# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: API token cannot be null or empty OKTA integration

Tags: spring-boot, wildfly, okta

I am trying to integrate OKTA to my spring boot application using SDK. But when I deploy the war file on Wildfly, getting this error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: API token cannot be null or empty

The token and orgurl are provided as Wildfly environment property. The property I have given is

```
okta.client.token 
okta.client.orgurl
```

Started wildfly as the standalone mode by using below command

```
/opt/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -bmanagement 0.0.0.0 --properties /opt/wildfly/jboss.property
```

jboss.property contain the property variables

I have verified the property variables in the wildfly management portal.

Thanks

Comment: I’m not much of a wildfly user, do the those env properties translate to system properties?  Which version of the Okta plugin are you using? Have you tried to set those properties via spring’s application.properties file?

Comment: @BrianDemers I tried to put the property on the application.property file, but not working. SDK able to fetch environment variable OKTA_CLIENT_TOKEN and OKTA_CLIENT_ORGURL successfully.

Comment: It _should_ be `application.properties` not `application.property` (not sure if that was a typeo or not)

Comment: @BrianDemers it was a typo!